# SSH session unresponsive - how do I active it or reboot by some other means

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, zerotier

Situation ...

- SSH into a remote Raspberry Pi running Buster via MobaTerm on Win10 PC over Zerotier
- It is in a remote location I cannot access because of the Coronavirus constraints.
- All was working just fine, responsive all going OK
- attempting to stop and restart RealVNC appeared to work but has "locked up" my SSH session
- have tried ^Z, ^C - nothing happens
- the parallel SFTP session that Mobaterm sets up is working just fine - I can see, access and edit files
- SFTP from other devices and using other tools works just fine.
- have tried starting SSH from a separate device, also via Zerotier - will not connect.
- All other applications running just fine (Motioneye, Nginx) and web pages displaying perfectly. The webserver can be accessed either over Zeortier or directly via external domain name with no problems.
- I have another Pi in the same location that I can still access via SSH etc etc.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get round this - reboot in some way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) while sftp is still working, place cron tab file to reboot it. 2) I wonder about DoS-ing it's still available services :-)

Comment: Thanks for that! I’ll rehearse the crontab idea first on a machine I can access physically to make sure I don’t screw it up!

Comment: I just checked the machine and, joy of joys, it now talks to me and joins to SSH and VNC ( which I will now avoid!)

Comment: Closed and solved. Things righted themselves, but thanks to maxim-sagaydachny for his idea that I will prepare myself to implement in event that this happens again! Once I can get near the device I will put it on a remotely controlled socket so that I can power off/on to reboot.